# Kinetic energy in combined rotational and translational motion

Tags: energy, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

If a body is free to move I have studied that any point can be assumed to be in translational motion with velocity of the centre of mass along with a pure rotational motion with $\omega$. For Kinetic Energy we can take the sum(obviously scalar sum) of kinetic energies in both cases, which is equal to $$\frac{1}{2} M (v_{COM})^2 + \frac{1}{2} (I_{COM})\omega ^ 2.$$

Why do we have to take pure rolling about centre of mass & translational motion with velocity of Centre of mass. Can't we take the velocity of any arbitrary point A & pure rolling about that point A too?

And if a rigid body is hinged about, say a massless rod and the rod itself moves with a velocity called $V_{hinge}$ , what should be kinetic energy now?

I think it should be
$$\frac{1}{2} M (V_{hinge})^2 + \frac{1}{2} I_{hinge} \omega ^ 2.$$

Here also, I have a similar question, why shouldn't pure rolling about any other point along with translational velocity of that point work? Is it so that the hinge force don't produce any torque?

Comment: [This post and its answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/559612) might be relevant.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/546761/392

Answer (score 3):

Angular velocity is a pseudo vector. That has two different interpretations.
In discussions of symmetry, it is taken to mean "axial-vector", which is made from the antisymmetric part of a rank-2 tensor:

$$ \tilde{\omega}_{ij} =  (r_iv_j - r_jv_i) $$

To avoid this complication, we generally use:

$$ \omega_i = \frac 1 2\epsilon_{ijk}\tilde{\omega}_{jk}=
(\vec r \times \vec v)_i$$

Hence the cross-product. It rotates like a vector, but is even under reflection (parity transformations).

The other meaning of pseudo-vector is that it depends on a choice of origin, while real vectors do not.

Consider a frictionless bead with velocity v confined to a circular hoop with radius r:

$$ \vec\omega = \vec r \times \vec v $$

with conserved angular momentum:

$$ \vec L = \vec \omega {\bf I} = m(\vec r \vec r) \vec v\propto mvr^2 $$

with zero torque:

$$ \vec{\tau} = \vec r \times \vec{F}_{\rm radial} = \vec{r} \times -\frac{mv^2}r  \hat r = 0 $$

Simple enough. We chose the origin at the center of the hoop.

Now put the origin on the hoop. (I'm not going to do the math), but clearly $L=0$ when the bead passes through the origin, and is maximized when the bead is furthest from the origin.

Now $\vec L$ isn't conserved. How?

Well, the centripetal force is no longer pointed at the origin so the torque is non-zero.

Just by moving the origin we created torques and changing angular momentum (and angular velocity). This is the pseudo-vector.

Such considerations should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

When a body is rolling (without slipping) every particle which make up the object have a velocity as shown by the blue arrows in the right-hand diagram, thus, in principle, one could evaluate the kinetic energy of each of the particles and sum them to find the total kinetic energy.

[image]

However it is much easier to combine the contributions from rotation about the centre of mass and the translation of the centre of mass.

In terms of your arbitrary point $A$ the kinetic energy could be evaluated and in particular note that if $A$ is the point of contact between the body and the surface with no slipping the kinetic energy is $\frac12 I_{\rm A}\omega^2$ where $I_{\rm A}$ is the moment of inertia of the body about $A$.
As with you hinge example there is no contribution form $\frac 12 m v_{\rm A}$ as $v_{\rm A}=0$.
Note that by using the parallel axis theorem $\frac12 I_{\rm A}\omega^2 = \frac 12 (I_{\rm CoM}+m r^2)\omega^2 = \frac 12 I_{\rm CoM}\omega^2 + \frac 12 m v_{\rm CoM}^2$ as for no slipping $v_{\rm CoM}=r\omega$.

It is likely that when you started the topic of rotational dynamics a lot of these equation were proved from first principles with a view of making it easier in the future to analyse a variety of situations and than these proofs once seen were often moved to the "distant" memory part of the brain.
An example of this sequence is [Chapter 16](https://openlearninglibrary.mit.edu/courses/course-v1:MITx+8.01.1x+3T2018/pdfbook/0/chapter/16/1) and later ones of an MIT Mechanics course textbook.

Answer (score 2):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

For arbitrary point A of the rigid body with 6 generalized coordinate, the kinetic energy is:

$$T=\frac 12 m\,\b v_A\cdot \b v_A+\frac 12\b \omega^T\,\b I_A\,\b\omega$$

were
$$\b v_A=\b v_{\rm CM}+\b\omega\times\b u\\
\b I_A=\b I_{\rm CM}-m\,\tilde{\b{u}}\,\tilde{\b{u}}\\
\b \omega=[\b J(\b \phi)]_{3\times 3}\,\dot{\b{\phi}}$$

- $~\b u~$ vector from the center of mass to point A
- $~\b\phi=[\phi_1~,\phi_2~,\phi_3]^T~$ generalized angle coordinate

Rigid body with hinge joint

$$\b v_A=0\quad\Rightarrow\\
T=\frac 12\b \omega^T\,\b I_A\,\b\omega\\
\b\omega=\b J(\phi_1)\dot{\phi_1}$$
$~\phi_1~$ is the generalized coordinate

**Example   2D Pendulum**

\begin{align*}
& \b\omega=\begin{bmatrix}
            0 \\
            0 \\
            \dot{\phi} \\
          \end{bmatrix}
\quad,\b I_{\rm CM}= \begin{bmatrix}
                   0 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & o & I_z \\
                 \end{bmatrix}\quad,
\b u=\begin{bmatrix}
       0 \\
       L/2 \\
       0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}\quad\Rightarrow\\\\
&\b I_A= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1/4\,m{L}^{2}&0&0\\  0&0&0
\\  0&0&1/4\,m{L}^{2}\end {array} \right]
\\\\&T=\frac{1}{2}\b\omega^T\,\b I_A\,\b\omega=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}\left(I_z+\frac{1}{4}\,m\,L^2\right)
  \end{align*}

---

$$\tilde{\b{u}}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-u_{{z}}&u_{{y}}\\   u_{
{z}}&0&-u_{{x}}\\  -u_{{y}}&u_{{x}}&0\end {array}
 \right]$$